# Browser not showing the changes made in CSS

Tags: php, css, netbeans

I am using Netbeans for PHP development.

If I make any change to CSS, it doesn't show in browser.Every time I have to close the NetBeans and then restart it to see the changes I made.

How can I show CSS updates without restarting the IDE?

Comment: What browser are you using to view the changes you've made?

Comment: I am using firefox ,chrome for some reasons doesn't show the full length page.i am actually beginner in this field :)...thnx

Comment: As others are suggesting below, it could most likely be that your browsers have cached your css file which means that it's loading an older version even though it's been updated.  You can do what's know as a 'hard refresh' which will clear your cache and reload the new css file.  If this doesn't solve your issue, then the issue is a bit more complicated than that and we'll most likely need more information about your testing environment.  Mainly if you are testing locally on your computer, or remotely on a server.

Answer (score 1):

So it could be two things. 
First, if you are on your localhost, check in your php.ini file if the OPCache is not activated.
If its activated add ";" to comment.
Careful, there is two php.ini file with MAMP WAMP XAMP, so check if it's the good one.

Second, check if you use chrome to disable the cache while using the dev tool. it can be done in the web devtools setting (could be the same with firefox).

May be it's another thing but try these two things.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a hard refresh CTRL + F5.

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading the page after removing `cookies` ... use `ctrl+shift+delete` to remove cookies from your browser.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using chrome press F12 then right click refresh button and select empty cache and hard reload